# Lowdb и Node.js. Поиск по значению, запись и чтение данных

Tags: база-данных, json, node.js

Работаю с Node.js.  При создании одного проекта использую lowdb.
Допустим в json файле есть массив который включает в себя два объекта с пятью элементами:

```
{"posts": [
{
  "id": "12345",
  "nameArr": "",
  "counter": 0,
  "testActivate": false,
  "menuData": false,
  },
{
  "id": "54321",
  "nameArr": "",
  "counter": 0,
  "testActivate": false,
  "menuData": false,
}
 ]}
```

Как правильно написать код для выполнения  следующих действий с данными? 
    1. Найти объект в массиве с id "12345" и прочитать значение элемента "counter".  Если (counter == 0) увеличить его значение на единицу. 
    2. Найти объект в массиве с id "54321", и прочитать значение элемента "testActivate". Если (testActivate == false)  тогда значение элемента "menuData" изменить на true.

PS: Корректна ли в данном случае такая конструкция ниже?

```
//index.js
//read menuData

const low = require('lowdb');
const db = low('db.json');

const post = db.get('posts').find({ id: "12345" }).value();
console.log(post.menuData); //read
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Верный вариант:

```
const lowdb = require('lowdb');
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync');
const adapter = new FileSync("database.json");
const db = lowdb(adapter);

const post = db.get('posts').find({ id: "12345" }).value();
console.log(post.menuData)
```